# Adding usermeta information during registration in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a woocommerce project and my requirement is that whenever a new user registration occurs there should an account number generated which should be mailed to him so I am trying to use the update_user_meta function but not understanding how to get the User_id for somebody who has not yet registered

Please check my code and advise

```
add_action('woocommerce_register_form', 'vmart_add_account_number');
function vmart_add_account_number() {
    global $wpdb;
    $userdata = array();
    $user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);
    $account_number = 1;
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'account_number', $account_number);
    $account_number++;
}
```

I have also tried this code

```
add_action('user_register', 'vmart_add_account_number', 10, 1);

function vmart_add_account_number($user_id)
{
    $accountnumber = 1;
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'account_number', $accountnumber);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Loic for helping me again..I will surely do more research on the info you gave..

Comment: You are welcome. come back later when you are ready and update your question with some code, to get better helped.

Answer (score 0):

For this thing you can use standard wordpress hook:

```
// Register subcustomer to same customer

add_action('user_register', 'vmart_add_account_number', 10, 1);

function vmart_add_account_number($user_id)
{
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'account_number', $account_number);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey for answering but Its not working  .. I am using the Woocommerce My Account registration form so will the user_register hook work on it..the code that I derived from the one that you gave me is updated in my Question